# Thick edges in Gephi

Tags: gephi, edges

Is there a way to force Gephi to use the same thickness for ALL edges?
For some reason my network has few (3 or 4) super thick edges and I dont have a clue why.

Ruth

Answer (score 3):

Apart from @MikaelF 's answer you can go to **Data Laboratory > Edges** and at the bottom of the Data lab press the button **Fill column with a value** and select **Weight**.

[image]

It is then just a matter of entering a value for the weight, e.g. 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because there was a duplicate edge in my database. Gephi then automatically calculates that that edge's weight is x times the normal weight. To see if Gephi weighed your edges differently during import, go to Data Laboratory/Edges (a small tab under the Workspace tab), then you can see and sort the weight column.